# Can't enable the network adapter on virtual box

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Pls help me in resolving this i can't enable the network adapter so that i can change my IP address.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question: if the network adapter isn't enabled, you don't have an IP address to change. You should have a drop-down list in the adapter name, but I can't say why it appears not to be there. If you can type in the box, try entering the adapter you want to use from the `ifconfig -s` list.

Comment: @heavyd - The questioner appears to be unable to add the _first_ adapter, though there may be related information in your link, especially the point about making sure that the VM is powered off, not suspended. But this does not make it a duplicate.

Comment: @AHF, it is essentially the same question: Why can't I make networking changes to a VM, all of the options are grayed out, to which the answer is make sure the VM is Powered Off, I don't see how its not the same question just worded slightly differently.

Comment: You are not on "nat network", you are on "nat" instead, i know very annoying, can can yrefer to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgVQbDe5iwE

Answer (score 3):

Shutdown the VM properly before trying to add a network adaptor. You cannot change settings while it is in a "saved" state.

Power up the VM, then go to power it off again, but in the following window select **`Power off the machine`** rather than `Save the machine state`.

[image]

You should then have access to the settings to add a network adaptor.